# Latex Table of Contents Adjustments

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to achieve the following with my current table of contents.
I want to remove the vertical spacing for specific items e.g. Declaration, Abstract etc.

Then I want everything aligned left, with no indentation for the numbering. 
**I'm using the standard**

```
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book} %reminder to add twoside command when printing
\pagestyle{plain}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Packages to use. %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}% support older LaTeX versions

\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}%
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tocbibind}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Setup line spacing for document %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{setspace}
%\singlespacing
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing
%\setstretch{1.1}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% THE BEGINNING %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
\blindtext
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BLahBlah}
\blindtext
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BLahBlahBlah}
\blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

To add the extra items to the TOC and \tableofcontents for the creation of my TOC.
[image: Current structure]

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What class are you using?

Comment: \documentclass[11pt, oneside]{book} %reminder to add twoside command when printing
\pagestyle{plain}

Comment: Any help guys? The class is book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Now there is a MWE in the question and I know that TOC entries for TOC, LOF and LOT etc. are required. But I do not understand what the comment

> The alignment between the numbering and title needs to be in line as well

means. So it is still a guess what the desired result is.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=20mm,left=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{expl3}

\usepackage{hyperref}% <- should be the last package

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \clist_map_inline:nn
    {chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
    {\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt,numwidth=3.8em]{tocline}{#1}}
  \clist_map_inline:nn
    {figure,table}
    {\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt]{tocline}{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  level=\chaptertocdepth,%
  beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,%
  indent=0em,%
  numwidth=3.8em,%
  entryformat=\textbf,%
  pagenumberformat=\textbf,%
  linefill=\hfill
]{tocline}{fmchapter}

\makeatletter
\let\l@origchapter\l@chapter
\newcommand*\usefmchapter{% define switch to fmchapter entry
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\addvspace{1em plus 1pt}% additional space in TOC before the first fmchapter entry
    \protect\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@fmchapter
  }%
}
\newcommand*\useorigchapter{% define switch to original chapter entry
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@origchapter
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\usefmchapter% <- switch
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
\blindtext
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BLahBlah}
\blindtext
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BLahBlahBlah}
\blindtext

\useorigchapter% <- switch
\blinddocument

\usefmchapter% <- switch
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusion}
\blindtext
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BLahBlah}
\blindtext
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BLahBlahBlah}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that you can/have to adjust `numwidth=3.8em` to your needs.

But if you want

[image]

then you have to use the value of `numwidth` for `indent` of `fmchapter`:

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  level=\chaptertocdepth,%
  beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,%
  indent=3.8em,% <- changed
  numwidth=3.8em,%
  entryformat=\textbf,%
  pagenumberformat=\textbf,%
  linefill=\hfill
]{tocline}{fmchapter}
```

---

**Original answer**

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question, so it is only a guess.
The following suggestion uses package `tocbasic` to declare an additional entry style in TOC:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \clist_map_inline:nn
    {chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
    {\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt]{tocline}{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
  level=\chaptertocdepth,%
  beforeskip=0pt plus .2pt,%
  indent=0pt,%
  numwidth=1.5em,%
  entryformat=\textbf,%
  pagenumberformat=\textbf,%
  linefill=\hfill
]{tocline}{fmchapter}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Declaration}\addcontentsline{toc}{fmchapter}{Declaration}
\blindtext
\chapter*{Abstract}\addcontentsline{toc}{fmchapter}{Abstract}
\blindtext
\chapter*{Dedication}\addcontentsline{toc}{fmchapter}{Dedication}
\blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: MWE added, the \clist_map_inline:nn provides an error on my compile.

Comment: Your answer works but doesn't fully do what I want. The alignment between the numbering and title needs to be in line as well.  How do I make use of the fmchapter \addcontentsline when using \usepackage{tocbibind}

Comment: That is the problem of missing MWEs. See my updated answer. But I am still not sure how the desired result looks like.

Comment: Your final update was simply brilliant. Thank you very much, you've interpreted what I wanted exactly and it works very well! Thank you very much!